# grep for substrings present for each string in file - shell script

Tags: shell, grep

I have a strings in a file like this:

```
 47:2016-10-25 20:24:21 - [HSM ]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s
 301:2016-10-26 08:01:01 - [HSM ]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s
```

I have one input string as date"2016-10-25" and another input string as "Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response".

I want to find the no. of strings present in the file. I tried with this:

```
  total_attempt=$(grep -c "$i\|\[HSM \]Handle Identity Request. Send 
  Identity Response. timeout: 1550s" $file_name
```

I believe | in the above syntax will not work.

Note: $i is the date as input

The output should be like:

```
 2016-10-25: = attempts = 2
```

But this is not working.

Sed commands will help, but i am not sure how?

Answer (score 0):

could you try this;

```
#!/bin/bash
file_name=yourFile
i="2016-10-25"
total_attempt=$(grep -c "$i\|\[HSM \]Handle Identity Request. Send Identity Response. timeout: 1550s" $file_name)
echo $total_attempt
```

Answer (score 0):

For `|` to work, you need to turn on extended regular expression, i.e. also pass the `-E` switch to grep.